# How to remove or display no arrows in WEPopover

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, popup, popover

my question is if it is posible to display no arrows with the WEPopover or if there are any way to display a popover without arrows in Iphone.
I could do that with a subview but in do know how to programing it.